# ITK: Cannot find ITKConfig.cmake file in ITK-5.2.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, itk

I've installed itk-5.2.1 with pip in an anaconda environment with Python 3.9.

On the other hand, I'm trying to run CMake to build Greedy.

In the Cmake console (i'm using linux) I'm asked about the directory where ITKConfig.cmake or itk-config.cmake is located.

I have been searching in ITK binaries directory in the anaconda environment files, but I didn't find it. Does anyone know where the path file is located?

Comment: probably duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027316/itk-cannot-find-itkconfig-cmake

Answer (score 0):

It is usually in `...\lib\cmake\ITK-5.2\ITKConfig.cmake`. One full path on my computer is `M:\a\Seg3D-deb\Externals\Install\ITK_external\lib\cmake\ITK-5.3\ITKConfig.cmake`.